# ASP.NET app cannot see files

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web app (VS 2017 Framework 4.5) that works fine in development. When I deploy to the web server and try to reference a file like this:

```
PdfBitmap tiffImage = new PdfBitmap(item.TIFPageLocation);
```

It returns a "Can't find file error". I even set up an if File.Exists() test and had the same result.

The file is a reference to another server like this: `\\myserver\myvolume1\00\12\7A\00127A90.TIF`.

When I run this path on the web server in WinExplorer it finds and open the TIF image in the default viewer. However the web app cannot see it for some reason.

This is likely some permissions issue but I'm not sure where.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Carl

Comment: The user that the server runs as probably doesn't have access.

Comment: Does the user account the website is hosted under have access to the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is likely a permissions issue.  Your web app will probably be running under an account that has limited rights (almost certainly without the rights to access anything on the domain).

You either need to:

a) elevate their rights (be very careful with this)

b) run your site under a new user context created specifically for this site with rights to reach the other server

c) put your images somewhere easier to access.

Answer (score 0):

Check your folder permission it should not have read access cross check that it's worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It was the account the app pool identity was associated with. That need to be set properly.